# What does $dx^n$ mean in the Leibniz's notation of the derivative?

Tags: real-analysis

Using Leibniz's notation we have that the second derivative of a function $f(x)$ is:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{d}{dx} f(x)\right) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} f(x)$$

And in general the $n$-th derivative is written as $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)$.

I get that when we iterate a function $n$ times we usually write $f^n(x)$ to denote it. Is it just notation or is there an actual meaning to $dx^n$? I assume there is a meaning to this because I have never seen the $n$-th derivative written as $\frac{d^n}{d^n x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is more or less just notation. $\mathrm d/\mathrm d x$ is taken as a differential operator with $f\to\frac{\mathrm d f}{\mathrm d x}$. So if we chain this operator with itself we get $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\frac{\mathrm d f}{\mathrm dx}$ which we then shorten to $\frac{\mathrm d\mathrm d f}{\mathrm d x\mathrm d x}=\frac{\mathrm d^2 f}{\mathrm d x^2}$ where $\mathrm d x$ is one symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have a meaning by itself, the meaning of the notation $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ cannot be decomposed in meanings of $d^n$, a meaning for the fraction, and a meaning for $dx^n$.

However the notation $dx^n$ by itself can represent the differential of the power function $x\mapsto x^n$ but this is unrelated to $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$.